# Replacing values between x and y in a mysql table as well as special characters

Tags: php, mysql, regex, replace

I need to remove price information from a specific mysql column. The price can either be in this format $ 54.99 or US Dollar 54.99

I already have a script that lets me replace the values one at a time, e.g. I can replace $ 54.99 with a blank space but theres hundreds of different values that need replacing.
How would I go about to have my script remove all the numbers as well as dollar signs and the text "US dollar"?

As an example: I have a column named book and a typical row has a text like this in it: "This book is great and costs US Dollar 54.99"

I would need to remove "US Dollar" and "54.99" so the remaining text would read: "This book is great and costs"

The script I am using looks like this:

```
// code here
if($showErrors) {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
}


$MJCONN = mysql_pconnect($hostname, $username, $password) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_select_db($database,$MJCONN);


$table_sql = 'SHOW TABLES';
$table_q = mysql_query($table_sql,$MJCONN) or die("Cannot Query DB: ".mysql_error());
$tables_r = mysql_fetch_assoc($table_q);
$tables = array();

do{
    $tables[] = $tables_r['Tables_in_'.strtolower($database)];
}while($tables_r = mysql_fetch_assoc($table_q));


$use_sql = array();

$rowHeading = ($queryType=='replace') ? 
        'Replacing \''.$search.'\' with \''.$replace.'\' in \''.$database."'\n\nSTATUS    |    ROWS AFFECTED    |    TABLE/FIELD    (+ERROR)\n"
      : 'Searching for \''.$search.'\' in \''.$database."'\n\nSTATUS    |    ROWS CONTAINING    |    TABLE/FIELD    (+ERROR)\n";

$output = $rowHeading;

$summary = '';

foreach($tables as $table) {

    $field_sql = 'SHOW FIELDS FROM '.$table;
    $field_q = mysql_query($field_sql,$MJCONN);
    $field_r = mysql_fetch_assoc($field_q);


    do {

        $field = $column;
        $type = $field_r['Type'];

        switch(true) {

            case stristr(strtolower($type),'char'): $typeOK = true; break;
            case stristr(strtolower($type),'text'): $typeOK = true; break;
            case stristr(strtolower($type),'blob'): $typeOK = true; break;
            case stristr(strtolower($field_r['Key']),'pri'): $typeOK = false; break; // DO NOT REPLACE PRIMARY-KEYS
            default: $typeOK = false; break;
        }

        if($typeOK) { 

            $handle = $table.'_'.$field;
            if($queryType=='replace') {
                $sql[$handle]['sql'] = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET '.$field.' = REPLACE('.$field.',\''.$search.'\',\''.$replace.'\')';
            } else {
                $sql[$handle]['sql'] = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$field.' REGEXP(\''.$search.'\')';
            }


            $error = false;
            $query = @mysql_query($sql[$handle]['sql'],$MJCONN) or $error = mysql_error();
            $row_count = @mysql_affected_rows() or $row_count = 0;


            $sql[$handle]['result'] = $query;
            $sql[$handle]['affected'] = $row_count;
            $sql[$handle]['error'] = $error;


            $output .= ($query) ? 'OK        ' : '--        ';
            $output .= ($row_count>0) ? '<strong>'.$row_count.'</strong>            ' : '<span style="color:#CCC">'.$row_count.'</span>            ';
            $fieldName = '`'.$table.'`.`'.$field.'`';
            $output .= $fieldName;
            $erTab = str_repeat(' ', (60-strlen($fieldName)) );
            $output .= ($error) ? $erTab.'(ERROR: '.$error.')' : '';

            $output .= "\n";
        }
    }while($field_r = mysql_fetch_assoc($field_q));
}
```

Comment: Want to do it frequently or rarely or once?

Comment: Write then its easy. What is the regex you want to replace. Can you guide as i could not find it. just the pattern/regular expression.

Comment: Fine. I try it on my localhost and update soon :)

Comment: Changed the $pat as you said. Hope for the better result :)

Comment: Edit your title as 'Remove a pattern from entire mysql column values' (if it seems better to you) and add the last comment in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mysql has no built in function for replace on the bases of regex so better you could do it in php. Only an id is needed (to use in update query) in your table. If it is not already, include it.

You may have explained something in your script (I could not understand it well), however this answer is just regarding the text of your question. Hopefully it would be helpful to remove all prices from your entire column once (where ever found).

After you get connected to database you need to modify your code as

```
$sql = "SELECT id,book FROM yourtable";    
$result = mysql_query($sql);    
if (!$result) 
{
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) 
{
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $book= $row['book'];
    //$pat='/(\$|(US Dollar)) \d+(\.\d+)?/';
    $pat = '/\$|(page)|(US)|(dollar)|(\d+)|~|\.|(sterling)/i';
    if(preg_match($pat, $book))
    {
       $book= preg_replace($pat, '', $book);
       $sql = "UPDATE yourtable set book='".$book."' where id='".$id."'";
       mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
```

**Edit** Changed The pattern (value of $pat) in response to your comment.
Edit 2: Now added the 'page' as well I had missed it last time

Comment: 1. Yes It van be done without id as select all from table and use complete row values as a criteria fro update query
2. Unable to understand your script, however all that you need can be done by this script